Cypress Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prevSubject')
I am using Cypress 5.2.0 and getting the following error:
TypeError
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prevSubject')

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.
Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.
We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
Check your console for the stack trace or click this message to see where it originated from.
This is the code, it happens even if it is all in a comment!
const waitUntil = (subject, checkFunction, originalOptions = {}) => {
if (!(checkFunction instanceof Function)) {
 throw new Error(``\``checkFunction\`` parameter should be a function. Found: ```${checkFunction}``);
 }
 const defaultOptions = {
 // base options
  interval: 200,
  timeout: 5000,
 // log options
 description: ``waitUntil``,
  log: true,
logger: Cypress.log,
 verbose: false,
 };
 const options = { ...defaultOptions, ...originalOptions };
let retries = Math.floor(options.timeout / options.interval);
 const check = (result) => {
if (result) {
 return result;
 }
if (retries < 1) {
 // signal failure, but do not throw
 return false;
 }
 return cy.wait(options.interval, { log: false }).then(() => {
 retries--;
 return resolveValue();
  });
 };
const resolveValue = () => { const result = checkFunction(subject);
 const isAPromise = Boolean(result && result.then);
 if (isAPromise) {
return result.then(check);
 }
 return check(result);
 };
return resolveValue();
 };
 Cypress.Commands.add('conditionallyWaitUntil', { prevSubject: 'optional' }, waitUntil);
